# Using Blade Templates for Views vs those to send Messages

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, messaging

I'm using Laravel 5 and have created an application that has invoices that contains orders which contain items. I have a nice view created using a blade template. Now I want to email that invoice - exactly as it appears in the view. From what I've read you can't just pass the object to the message but have to create an array. Is that correct?

I'd like to pass that same array to the blade template and the message. My problem is that when I pass the array to the message I'm forced to access the variables like so:

```
{{ $order_number }}
```

and when I pass the array to the blade template I have to access it as an array like so:

```
{{ $invoice['invoice_number'] }}
```

Here's my code for the message:

```
public function sendInvoice($invoice_id)
{
    $invoice = new \App\Invoice;
    $arrInvoice = $invoice->createInvoiceArray($invoice_id);
    $data = $arrInvoice;
    \Mail::send('messages.invoices.cls', $data, function($message) use ($data)
    {
        $message->from('dylan@dylanglockler.com', 'Dylan Glockler');
        $message->to('dylan@dylanglockler.com', 'Love Laundry')->subject('CLS Tracking - Invoice');
    });
}
```

I must be doing something wrong here  - Laravel is so keen, I think I must be doing something wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to tap into laravel's `toArray()` function for this.

```
public function sendInvoice($invoice_id)
{
    $arrInvoice = \App\Invoice::find($invoice_id)->toArray();
    $data['arrInvoice'] = $arrInvoice;
    \Mail::send('messages.invoices.cls', $data, function($message)
    {
        $message->from('dylan@dylanglockler.com', 'Dylan Glockler');
        $message->to('dylan@dylanglockler.com', 'Love Laundry')->subject('CLS Tracking - Invoice');
    });
}
```

Then in your view:

```
{{$arrInvoice['invoice_number']}}
```

The reason why you have to convert your data from object to array is so that laravel can access the information if ever you choose to use queues.

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json

Comment: I tried that - but in the blade template 'messages.invoices.cls' called by Mail::send I'm only able to access the elements directly and not using the array like you suggested. That works in a blade generated by a View though - that difference is exactly my problem. Unless there's some other way to pass the array into the Mail model?

Comment: Are you sure? I changed the format of the `$data` variable. And no, that's the only way to pass variables to the mail view.

Comment: AH! you're correct! I missed that - so sorry - late night, blurry eyes.. recovering from stolen laptop this week.. appreciate the help - I'll mark it as answered!

Comment: Hint for debugging mails: Use `\Log::info(\View::make(\messages.invoices.cls',$data)->render());` This will render your mail's HTML completely in your logs found at `/storage/logs/`